# Is there an issue with having multiple clients sharing the same nservicebus databus channel?

Tags: azure, nservicebus

Here is my setup:
I have a azure web role and a worker role both configured to use a databus channel via blob storage. I now need to add another web client that requires a databus.

Is it acceptable to use the same databus channel or will this cause issues related to the clean up operation of messages that happen behind the scenes?

**Update:**
I am seeing this error in the event log of my web role:

```
An unhandled exception occurred. Type: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.StorageClientException Process ID: 2968
Process Name: w3wp
Thread ID: 12
AppDomain Unhandled Exception for role My.Assembly.Web_IN_4
Exception: The specified blob does not exist.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.ExecuteAndWait()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlob.FetchAttributes(BlobRequestOptions options)
   at NServiceBus.DataBus.Azure.BlobStorage.BlobStorageDataBus.DeleteExpiredBlobs()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading._TimerCallback.PerformTimerCallback(Object state)

Inner Exception: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.EventHelper.ProcessWebResponse(WebRequest req, IAsyncResult asyncResult, EventHandler`1 handler, Object sender)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use the same channel, as both sender and receiver must be able to access it and you can only configure one, this implies that it has to be shared.

It should not cause issues for cleanup, seeing anything strange? If so, let me know!

Kind regards,
Yves

Comment: I am seeing failures in the event log of the web role. I will post the error in my original question.

Comment: a contributing factor may be that i have multiple instances on the web role configured (5 to be exact). So there is probably a race condition in regards to the fetching of the blob and the deletion in the clean up process? one instance is probably getting the list and by the time it goes to delete it another instance has done so.

Comment: Indeed, have been able to reproduce it. It does not seem to impact the behavior of nsb in any way, the next timer will simply trigger again and continue it's work as expected. All I can do is catch the exception and log it, but not sure you would win anything here except for getting a warning instead of an error message...

Comment: yes but i wonder if the w3wp.exe process termination is causing the webrole to go into a recycle? it is definitely causing a process termination. that would be bad. This is from an entry in the application event log immediately following the exception: "Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception."

Comment: According to .net docs the timer is handling this case, but if you see  a recycle that would not be the case. I'll handle the exception in that case.

Comment: Is it possible for you to upgrade to a more recent version? Typically we don't patch versions that old...

Comment: you mean of nservicebus? I am using 3.2.8 currently.

Comment: yes, maybe now is the time :) Do you think upgrading will resolve this issue? i was about to investigate adding an unhandled exception handler in the roleentrypoint run method to deal with this - yuk. Rather not have to go there.

Comment: I'll create you a 3.3.5 branch that fixes this issue, or you can wait till 4.0 gets released (which shouldn't be to far off either)

Comment: i will go with the 3.3.5 branch if available. thanks for your help.

Comment: By the way i noticed that in the deleteexpiredblobs method in the BlobStorageDataBus.cs file you are catching StorageServerException. The actual exception raised for the 404 condition is a StorageClientException. this would account for why it is unhandled.